# How to use auto with const and & in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a method that returns const A &.

If I want to use auto, what is the right way to do it. Is this OK?

```
const auto &items = someObject.someMethod();
```

I see some people do this:

```
auto &items = someObject.someMethod();
```

I am not sure which one to use, and what are the differences really...

Edit:

In this case, are these two equivalent?

```
auto items = someObject.someMethod();
auto &items = someObject.someMethod();
```

Comment: "When in doubt, always clarify your intent."

Comment: Your edit is quite a different problem (to be answered with *"NO"* and some references to the automatic type deduction rules).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Even though the two forms are equivalent *in this case*, I would choose the first form anyway, since it communicates better the fact that your piece of code does not need to modify the state of the object returned by `someMethod()`.

So my advice is to go for this:

```
const auto &items = someObject.someMethod();
```

Comment: I edited my original post, so what happens in this case? Are those two cases the same?

Comment: @user2381422: No, they are not. But please, keep in mind, that changing your questions or adding new questions 1 hour after people have responded to the old one is not a very appropriate way of using SO. As long there is a post that answers your original question, you should accept it. And if you have a new question, ask a new question :) - possibly linking it to the old question if the two are related.

Comment: I wonder if `const x = expression;` could be added to C++ as a shortcut for `const auto x = expression;`

Comment: @robson3.14 I guess that would make parsing C++ code even more insane that it already is.

Answer (score 9):

In your case, there is no difference. The type which `auto` represents will be deduced to `const A` in both cases, so the type of `items` will be `const A&`.

There is a difference in what the "self-documented semantics" of the code is. The `const auto &` clearly states "I want a reference to what is returned, and I will not modify it." Just `auto &` says simply "I want a reference to what is returned."

Comment: The `const` will be deduced if *not* explicitly present.

Comment: @Potatoswatter someMethod returns const & A

Comment: I edited my original post, so what happens in this case? Are those two cases the same?

Answer (score 9):

More explicitness is usually better, the exception being separation of concerns. Implementation details shouldn't be mentioned on the client side of an interface.

If the receiver isn't supposed to care how the object is being received, then perfect forwarding is the way to go.

```
auto && items = someObject.someMethod();
```

Allowing `const` to be deduced in `auto` and, for example, binding a temporary value to `auto &` would be a major code smell for me.

- `auto const &` should mean read-only
- `auto &` should mean read-write
- `auto &&` should mean catch all, perhaps adopting a return by value object