# Difference between const auto & and auto & if object of reference is const

Tags: c++, constants, auto

```
// case 1
const int i = 42;
const auto &k = i;

// case 2
const int i = 42;
auto &k = i;
```

Do we need the `const` keyword before `auto` in this scenario? After all, a reference (`k`) to an auto-deduced type will include the top level `const` of the object (***`const`*** `int i`). So I believe `k` will be a reference to an integer that is constant (`const int &k`) in both cases.

If that is true, does that mean that `const auto &k = i;` in case 1 is replaced by the compiler as just `const int &k = i;` (`auto` being replaced with `int`)? Whereas in case 2, `auto` is replaced with `const int`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use auto with const and & in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16809934/how-to-use-auto-with-const-and-in-c) (though this one has better title, just I would remove those `k`s).

Comment: Both are similar for compiler. But as human reader, I prefer the first one.

Comment: I wonder who found this "unclear". There's no lacking in clarity, you expressed yourself very well.

Comment: @StoryTeller - A maintenance script identified it and posted it to the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/43842532#43842532) room. I'm guessing it is a Type I error in the script. The question was misclassified and incorrectly rejected.

Comment: @jww - Are you telling me the bot cast that vote?

Comment: @StoryTeller - No, I'm only saying a script identified the question as potentially problematic. I'm guessing a human moved against the question after it was posted to the room.

Comment: @StoryTeller@jww can you clarify what you guys are talking about? I am new to stack overflow so I am not following. did someone report my question because they thought it to be a duplicate?

Comment: @SteveCho - You can only address one person with a mention(@). jww didn't get pinged. As for your question, the SOCVR is a chat where users who care about content quality work together to remove bad content. There are bots who read new posts and bring it to the attention of the chat if they seem like bad questions. But it's still people who need to cast the close votes. jww and I were discussing the close votes on your post.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`auto` keyword automatically decides the type of the variable at compile time.

In your first case, `auto` is reduced to `int` where it's reduced to `const int` in the second case. So, both of your cases are reduced to the same code as:

```
const int &k = i;
```

However, it's better to have the const explicitly for better readability and to make sure your variable **TRULY** is `const`.

Comment: It also means "I want this to be a const reference, no matter whether it was already const before" because whether it was const before isn't really relevant to whether you want to add const now.

Answer (score 4):

Type deduction with `auto` works like template argument type deduction with a few exceptions that don't apply in the given example. Hence

```
const int i = 42;
const auto& k1 = i; // same as const int& k1 = i;
auto& k2 = i; // same as (const int)& k2 = i;
```

It is probably more readable to add the `const` qualifier nevertheless.

Here is another example where favoring brevity with `auto` is misleading:

```
int *i;
const auto k1 = i; // same as int* const k1 = i;
const auto *k2 = i;  // same as const int *k2 = i;
```

In the first case, the object that `i` points to can be modified through `k1`, in the second case, it can't.

Comment: "with a few exceptions" Can you give an example? I was not aware that there were any differences :)

Comment: @Rakete1111 You can have `auto a = { 1, 2, 3 };`, which deduces a `std::initializer_list<int>`, but `template<class T> void f(T&&) {}` can't be called via `f({1, 2, 3})`.

Comment: Ahh that's what you mean. But there is no difference in the actual deduction, like a an expression that is deduced to two different types with `auto` and template deduction?

Comment: @Rakete1111 No, that I would find quite disturbing :) Is the wording misleading in the answer?

Comment: Not at all, just curious :)

Answer (score 4):

Hi and welcome to stack overflow.

As this little test program shows, no matter how you specify the type of `k`, the compiler will never let you lose the constness of `i`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>

#define XSTR(s) STR(s)
#define STR(s) #s

template<class T> 
struct type;

template<>
struct type<int>
{
    static std::string name() { return "int"; }
};

template<class T>
struct type<T&&>
{
    static std::string name() { return type<T>::name() + " &&"; }
};

template<class T>
struct type<T&>
{
    static std::string name() { return type<T>::name() + " &"; }
};

template<class T>
struct type<T const>
{
    static std::string name() { return type<T>::name() + " const"; }
};

#define REPORT_CONST(decl, var, assign) \
{ \
    decl var = assign; \
    do_it(STR(decl var = assign;), var); \
}

template<class Var> 
void do_it(const char* message, Var&&)
{
    std::cout << "case: " << message << " results in type: " << type<Var>::name() << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    const int i = 42;

    REPORT_CONST(const auto &, k, i);
    REPORT_CONST(auto &, k, i);
    REPORT_CONST(auto &&, k, std::move(i));
    REPORT_CONST(auto const &&, k, std::move(i));
    REPORT_CONST(int const&, k, i);
    // REPORT_CONST(int &, k, i); // error: binding reference of type 'int&' to 'const int' discards qualifiers
}
```

Expected results:

```
case: const auto & k = i; results in type: int const &
case: auto & k = i; results in type: int const &
case: auto && k = std::move(i); results in type: int const &
case: auto const && k = std::move(i); results in type: int const &
case: int const& k = i; results in type: int const &
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7c72c8ebcf42c351

Note also the decay of named r-values to l-values.

Answer (score 2):

There is a slight difference in first case `auto` will be deduced to `const int` and in the second case to `int` (as you explcitly stated the const).

[cpp-reference states](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto)

> The keyword auto may be accompanied by modifiers, such as const or &, which will participate in the type deduction. For example, given const auto& i = expr;, the type of i is exactly the type of the argument u in an imaginary template template void f(const U& u) if the function call f(expr) was compiled. Therefore, auto&& may be deduced either as an lvalue reference or rvalue reference according to the initializer, which is used in range-based for loop.

**So for you this means**

```
// case 1
const int i = 42;   
const auto &k = i;   // auto -> int

// case 2
const int i = 42;
auto &k = i;  // auto -> const int
```

More important in my opinion is, however, that the intent is stated more clearly if you state const explcitly and the guarantees the constness. Therefore in this case I would clearly prefer it.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is correct, i.e. there is no difference in regards to the compiled result. What's important to note is that **the `auto&` version is *coupling* the `const`-ness of the `k` reference with the `const`-ness of the variable `i`**. I figured since the question is titled '*Difference between const auto & and auto & ...*' then it's important to emphasize the pragmatic difference here, in which if you don't put a the `const` keyword, you cannot guarantee the reference will have this *cv-qualification*. In some scenarios where this is desired, **why leave it to chance that `i` will remain `const` in the future?**