# Where is the const& args stored?

Tags: c++

Here is the function definition

```cpp
const int& test_const_ref(const int& a) {
  return a;
}
```

and calling it from `main`

```cpp
int main() {
  auto& x = test_const_ref(1);
  printf("%d, %p\n", x, &x);
}
```

output as following

```sh
 ./debug/main
>>> 1, 0x7ffee237285c
```

and here is the disassembly code of `test_const_ref`

```cpp
test_const_ref(int const&):
    pushq  %rbp
    movq   %rsp, %rbp
    movq   %rdi, -0x8(%rbp)
    movq   -0x8(%rbp), %rax
    popq   %rbp
    retq
```

The question is: where does the variable `x` alias or where is the number `1` I passed to function `test_const_ref` stored ?

Comment: There's a temporary object created that's only guaranteed to survive til the end of the assignment statement to x. Every access to this variable results in undefined behavior.

Comment: @Klaus [maybe you could reference this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52204122/difference-between-const-auto-and-auto-if-object-of-reference-is-const)

Comment: The type is deduced as `const int&` but the reference is still not valid. Try running with an address sanitizer.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I added the program output

Comment: What output of a program that has undefined behaviour is supposed to demonstrate?

Comment: Even if it compiles and the result is what you expect, the code is still broken!

Comment: @Klaus many thx, I got it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code exhibits [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) - the function `test_const_ref` returns a reference to a temporary, which lives until the end of the full-expression (the `;`), and any dereference of it afterwards accesses a dangling reference.

Appearing to work is a common manifestation of UB. The program is still wrong. With optimization on, for example, [Clang 12 -O2](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/9ajofYKd4) prints: `0`.

Note - there's no error in the function `test_const_ref` itself (apart from a design error). The UB is in `main`, where the dereference of the dangling `int&` happens during a call to `printf`.

Where the temporary `int` is stored exactly is implementation detail - but in many cases (in a Debug build, when a function isn't inlined), it would be stored on the stack:

```
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        mov     dword ptr [rbp - 12], 1      # Here the 1 is stored in the stack frame
        lea     rdi, [rbp - 12]
        call    test_const_ref(int const&)
        mov     qword ptr [rbp - 8], rax
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rbp - 8]
        mov     esi, dword ptr [rax]
        mov     rdx, qword ptr [rbp - 8]
        movabs  rdi, offset .L.str
        mov     al, 0
        call    printf
```

So any subsequent use of the returned reference will access memory at `[rbp - 12]`, that may already have been re-used for other purposes.

---

Note also that the compiler doesn't actually generate assembly from C++ code; it merely uses the C++ code to understand the *intent*, and generates *another program* that produces the intended output. This is known as the [as-if rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if). In the presence of undefined behavior, the compiler becomes free from this restriction, and may generate *any* output, rendering the program meaningless.

Comment: That's make sense to me and help me a lot. Thank you very much. Since I haven't got enough reputation, so sorry that I can't vote you. : )

Answer (score 1):

Good answers are already been given, but *wrapperm* explained this topic very well [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576489/where-are-constant-variables-stored-in-c). It's going to be stored on the stack in most implementations i'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

### 1. The function

The language doesn't define where arguments to functions are stored. Different ABIs, for different platforms, define this.

Typically, a function argument, before any optimization, is stored on the stack. A reference is no different in this respect. What's actually stored would be a pointer to the refered-to object. Think of it this way:

```
const int* test_const_ref(const int* a) {
  return a;
}
```

### 2. The temporary

If you were to declare a variable `int foo;` and call `test_const_ref(foo)`, you know that the result would refer to `foo`. Since you're calling it with a temporary, all bets are off: As @fabian notes in a comment, the language only guarantees the value exist until the end of the assignment statement. Afterwards

In practice, and in your case: A compiler which allocates stack space for the temporary integer `1` will have `x` refer to that place, and will not use it for something else before `x` is defined. But if your compiler optimizes that stack allocation away - e.g. passes `1` via a register - then `x` has nothing to refer to and may hold junk. It might even be undefined behavior (not quite sure about that). If you're lucky, you'll [get a compiler warning about it](https://godbolt.org/z/Gn79xGveE) (GodBolt.org).

Comment: Sorry for missing the complier I used. I try the program with Clang, everything went well, but got warning with gcc